Select non-adjacent points from a circle of m numbers.

Suppose numbers $1, 2, ...,m (m \ge 3)$ are placed in order around a circle. For k $\le$ $\lfloor m/2 \rfloor$, show that the number of k-element subsets of these m integers with no two elements adjacent is: $\frac{m}{k}  {m - k - 1 \choose k-1}$

I am aware of other solutions, but I am wondering if it is possible to do this with PIE. My approach was for every subset in S (set of all k-element subsets), define property i if i elements are adjacent. Then, $ω(x) = m {m-x\choose k-x}$. Then, $E(0) = |S| - ω(0) + ω(1)... + (-1)^k ω(k)$. This is wrong, and looking back, this setup for PIE doesn't even make sense. If possible, can anyone help me see a valid setup for PIE with this problem?

small issue but should the statement read $k\le \lfloor m/2 \rfloor$?
